# Speeding up JavaScript function that changes colour of div-element constructed 'led display'

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, optimization

### Background Info

For a project I'm working on I need to simulate a row of LEDs that can display different numbers in binary. Using lots of div elements with `border-radius: 50%`, I can make rows of 'LEDs'. A JavaScript function can then apply different css classes to change the colour of each element to simulate it being on or off. Another feature that I have is a tooltip that displays the numerical value that the LEDs are displaying when you hover your mouse over them.

### The Problem

The problem I'm having is the performance of this approach. This is because my web page will be using dozens of these rows and each row will have its value updated every screen refresh via `requestAnimationFrame()`. Currently, updating every instance of the LED rows on my page takes about 5ms on my laptop. This is definitely under the 16.6ms we have for each frame at 60Hz - however there are a number of other things that also need to be done each frame for my project and this does leave little time for those.

### An Example

An example of my current implementation is available on js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dL6jq7or/25/. Click the 'benchmark' text and check the console to see how long it took to update the row of leds 50,000 times. You can use this to quickly evaluate the performance of any ideas you come up with.

Note: I set the display to a different value each time to avoid any clever tricks a browser might do if it detects no actual changes take place. The real application of these LED rows will almost always give them a different value each time so this makes the benchmark more realistic.

### What I've already tried to speed it up

I cached the references to the LEDs in the `led_strips` object which gave a small perf boost becaue the browser did not have to do `document.getElementById()` each time any more.

I heard that adding/removing a css class to and from an element was faster than changing its css properties with JavaScript directly. This is why the code adds or removes the `on` class to change the state of the leds.

I found that first checking if the led div had the `on` class before trying to remove it (and vice versa) gave a small perf boost.

### Notes

The LED strips have no fixed size - the number of leds in them should only be determined by the number of `led` class divs contained in them.

Not all LED strips will have a tooltip - if they should have one the container div will have the `tooltip-enabled` class and contain a `tooltip-content` div.

You will see I commented out a section of the `display_number_on_leds` function that only updated the tooltip when it was visible. This check gives a large perf boost but means that if you hover over the strip after it has been changed, the tooltip may show the wrong value. This is not acceptable.

Most of the time spent by a browser that is changing the displayed number seems to be in re-calculating the layout/style of the page. Avoiding this would surely increase performance but I'm not sure how to do it.

### Summary

Can anyone see a way to speed up the `display_number_on_leds` function that preserves the functionality I currently have? If it is not possible for this approach to work faster, are there any alternative approaches that could be more faster (a canvas maybe?).

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just dumped on an external site. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit accordingly. (In exchange the rest of the explanation could be cut back a little maybe, that might be rather TL;DR territory already for some.)

Comment: This is some good JS code. You use bitwise operators, you cache DOM elements, use functions I didn't even know like `String.repeat` or `Number.toString`... I see no possibility of dramatic speed improvement in your code. IMO it's pretty much as fast as it can get. (FYI your benchmark takes between 650 and 700ms on my machine in Chrome)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback on the code. I suspected there may be little room for improvement but I'm not the expert so I asked.

Comment: As for the editing of my question, should I include some key snippets of code in the question itself? I put it all on jsfiddle because I didn't want to make the question too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not setting any HTML in the tooltip, only text, you can use one of `nodeValue`, `textContent` or `innertext` instead. [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue) seems to give the best result here though with a speed increase of more than 50% for me on Chrome 66.

Running your original code (using `innerHTML`) 10 times gives me:

```
50,000 iterations: 483.121826171875ms
50,000 iterations: 430.60400390625ms
50,000 iterations: 431.64599609375ms
50,000 iterations: 454.813232421875ms
50,000 iterations: 428.945068359375ms
50,000 iterations: 451.15673828125ms
50,000 iterations: 436.782958984375ms
50,000 iterations: 432.094970703125ms
50,000 iterations: 551.495849609375ms
50,000 iterations: 442.85400390625ms
```

Using `tooltip.childNodes[0].nodeValue = text;`

```
50,000 iterations: 212.26611328125ms
50,000 iterations: 198.85595703125ms
50,000 iterations: 206.324951171875ms
50,000 iterations: 201.528076171875ms
50,000 iterations: 202.0048828125ms
50,000 iterations: 195.52685546875ms
50,000 iterations: 207.598876953125ms
50,000 iterations: 202.48291015625ms
50,000 iterations: 207.677001953125ms
50,000 iterations: 197.98583984375ms
```

Using `tooltip.textContent = text;`

```
50,000 iterations: 259.39892578125ms
50,000 iterations: 221.156005859375ms
50,000 iterations: 238.042236328125ms
50,000 iterations: 212.44189453125ms
50,000 iterations: 221.1201171875ms
50,000 iterations: 225.68212890625ms
50,000 iterations: 226.552001953125ms
50,000 iterations: 209.56494140625ms
50,000 iterations: 215.00439453125ms
50,000 iterations: 222.412109375ms
```

Using `tooltip.innerText = text;`

```
50,000 iterations: 208.27099609375ms
50,000 iterations: 196.996826171875ms
50,000 iterations: 204.372802734375ms
50,000 iterations: 208.3291015625ms
50,000 iterations: 266.80810546875ms
50,000 iterations: 203.071044921875ms
50,000 iterations: 208.48876953125ms
50,000 iterations: 206.7939453125ms
50,000 iterations: 203.4111328125ms
50,000 iterations: 214.489013671875ms
```

**Edit**

Aside from the above there are a few more things you could do that would improve the performance a bit.

**1.**

The `num_dec_digits` and `num_hex_digits` do not change values between iterations and since they are only depentent on the amount of leds these can be calculated in `get_led_references()` instead:

```
function get_led_references(id) {
  var ref = document.getElementById(id);
  var has_tooltip = ref.children[0].className == "tooltip_content";
  var leds = Array.prototype.slice.call(ref.children);
  var references = {
    leds: leds,
    tooltip: has_tooltip ? leds.shift() : null
  };

  var log10_pow2 = Math.log10(Math.pow(2, leds.length));
  references.num_dec_digits = Math.ceil(log10_pow2);
  references.num_hex_digits = Math.ceil(log10_pow2 / Math.log10(16));

  return references;
}
```

Of course, if doing this then `display_number_on_leds()` will have to be changed accordingly.

**2.**

In the `get_padded_num()` function you are currently allocating new strings that are longer than you need. At least with the sample data you've provided, a while loop that's prepending the padding character seems to perform 10-20% faster:

```
function get_padded_num(number, length, base) {
  var str = number.toString(base);
  while (length > str.length) {
    str = '0' + str;
  }

  return str;
}
```

And so, with the added modifications, execution times are now:

```
50,000 iterations: 165.459716796875ms
50,000 iterations: 169.538818359375ms
50,000 iterations: 176.2109375ms
50,000 iterations: 170.885986328125ms
50,000 iterations: 167.305908203125ms
50,000 iterations: 169.608154296875ms
50,000 iterations: 168.797119140625ms
50,000 iterations: 175.070068359375ms
50,000 iterations: 165.182861328125ms
50,000 iterations: 169.580810546875ms
```